# CSS positioning span inside div

Tags: html, css

I think I miss something, but I have following structure

```css
.improvement_request_current {
  display: block;
  background: #777;
}

.improvement_request_current_title {
  background-color: #999;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: auto 0;
  vertical-align: center;
  color: blue;
}

.improvement_request_current_value {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="improvement_request_current">
  <span class="improvement_request_current_title">Just some text</span>
  <textarea class="improvement_request_current_value" rows="6" cols="50" maxlength="4096"></textarea>
</div>
```

In my opinion left part should be vertical aligned by center, but CSS have other opinion ) I've tried `block/inline-block/inline` variants with `margin: auto 0/vertical-align` variants with no success. What I'm doing wrong?

P.S. Without using flex and tables please. This is management constraints (

Comment: take a look at css flexbox. thank me later :-)

Comment: @AhmedTagAmer "the left part should be vertical aligned". what is not clear?

Comment: @GertB. thanks, I know about it, but I can't use it, this is a head direction. As I can't use table :/

Comment: Ranas answer shows you exactly how you should do that. Using tables is a no-go indeed.

Comment: @GertB. yes. I upvote answer because it's good and straight. But I have constraints and can't use it. May be outdated browser with no flex support or something, I don't know. Earlier there was float left; and top aligned which works 2 years, but new HR says it must be changed (

Comment: Flexbox is supported by all modern browsers. If the browser is that outdated so it does not support flexbox, it shouldn't be used anymore.  And not only because of missing functionality. There is another way: you can give the span a `display:block;` min height of 100% and use the `margin: auto 0;` But i would not recommend that

Comment: vertical-align:middle to text-area

Comment: @GertB. I discover the reason with flex and tables denied. Outdated browser but for reason. It's a web-server on production equipment and machines, which are 10years+ with build-in client . Some type of ie6 i think. And yes main reason were center instead of middle, so insulting mistake (

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: flex` property and it make easy to align the content.
Along with it use `align-items: center;` to vertically center align

```css
.improvement_request_current {
  display: block;
  background: #777;
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
}

.improvement_request_current_title {
  background-color: #999;
  color: blue;
}

.improvement_request_current_value {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div class="improvement_request_current">
  <span class="improvement_request_current_title">Just some text</span>
  <textarea class="improvement_request_current_value" rows="6" cols="50" maxlength="4096"></textarea>
</div>
```

Also one other method can be providing fixed `height` to parent and child(here given `100px`) and than `vertical-align: middle;`.

> But I don't recommend this method which you can see by removing comments from the `background` property and see that it is spanning out of parent element

```css
.improvement_request_current {
  display: block;
  background: #777;
}

.improvement_request_current_title {
  /*background-color: #999;*/
  color: blue;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.improvement_request_current_value {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="improvement_request_current">
  <span class="improvement_request_current_title">Just some text</span>
  <textarea class="improvement_request_current_value" rows="6" cols="50" maxlength="4096"></textarea>
</div>
```

[Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif) has given a short and simple solution, using `vertical-align: middle` to `text-area` will solve your problem

```css
.improvement_request_current {
  display: block;
  background: #777;
}

.improvement_request_current_title {
  background-color: #999;
  color: blue;
}

.improvement_request_current_value {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle
}
```

```html
<div class="improvement_request_current">
  <span class="improvement_request_current_title">Just some text</span>
  <textarea class="improvement_request_current_value" rows="6" cols="50" maxlength="4096"></textarea>
</div>
```

Comment: The one and only correct way! Should be the accepted answer.

Comment: And I should accept if no P.S. in question with constraints. I know that this is a right choice, but not an option for me (

Comment: @Rana indeed. I don't see any (valid) reason for not using flexbox. It IS supported by all modern browsers.

Comment: Yes, @GertB. also DuhVir `vertical-align` property has `middle` value instead of `center`